# Cannot resolve symbol R in android studio 1.2.2 on windows 8

Tags: java, android, xml, facebook-android-sdk

While I am trying to run or debug the code,it shows the error- cannot resolve symbol R.

Solution I have tried,

- clean project
- Sync project with gradle file
- Invalidate caches/restart..
- restart android studio and laptop
- Android-sdk build tools 22

I have posted code of different files below. Hope anyone can find the solution.

**activity_login_with_fb.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"   
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.xyz.phase1.loginWithFb">

<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

**AndroidMainfest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.xyz.phase1" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".openingActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".loginWithFb"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login_with_fb" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
     android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>


    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
  </application>

</manifest>
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.xyz.phase1"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
 }

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
   compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
   compile project(':facebook')
}
```

**loginWithfb.java**

```
public class loginWithFb extends FragmentActivity 
        {
             CallbackManager callbackManager;
             AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
             AccessToken accessToken;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_with_fb);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(
                AccessToken oldAccessToken,
                AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
            // Set the access token using
            // currentAccessToken when it's loaded or set.
        }
    };
    // If the access token is available already assign it.
    accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
 }
@Override
 public View onCreateView(
        LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_login_with_fb, container,
 false);

 LoginButton loginButton=(LoginButton)view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");

    // Callback registration
 loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, 
 new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {

        }
      });
       return view;
      }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution (in my case). My problem was that the path to the project was to long - some of the folders path were more than 255 char (I thought that that was only a problem in the late 90'). Everything compiles after I moved the  project to another path (a short path)